# showing the longest distance for each bike and a green icon if over 100

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I asked a simpler version of this question at [date and miles when over 100, otherwise return red traffic light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512025/date-and-miles-when-over-100-otherwise-return-red-traffic-light) and then realized I oversimplified my query.

I asked a new question because a solution was provided to my original question, but I asked the wrong question.

Here's the jist:

I had the silly goal of riding a century on each bike this year.

I want to create a status dashboard that has each bike with an icon indicating it's been done, green for yes, red for no.

Additionally, if it is yes, I want to populate the ride_date and ride_miles.

The second criteria is easy enough to do, the SQL query I have is:

```
SELECT
r.bike_name,
r.ride_date,
r.ride_miles
FROM rides r
JOIN bikes b
  on r.bike_name=b.bike_name
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(r.ride_date, '%Y')='$current_year' and r.ride_user = '$athlete' and b.bike_retired = 'No' AND ride_miles > 100
```

I experimented with the JOINS of my other question and adding my where clause to the join.  They worked good if I was the only user in the table and I didn't have to check if the bike was retired.  Once I added those portions it got all messed up and once again I'm lost.

Once I can get the right data back I can use PHP to massage it.  I keep thinking I need an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF` to return a different color depending on whether the threshold has been met.

```
SELECT r.bike_name, r.ride_date, r.ride_miles,
       IF(r.ride_miles > 100, 'green', 'red') AS color
FROM rides AS r
JOIN bikes AS b ON r.bike_name = b.bike_name
WHERE YEAR(r.ride_date) = $current_year
  AND r.ride_user = '$athlete'
  AND b.bike_retired = 'No'
```

Comment: That's kind of cool, I had no idea you could do that.  The data is probably sortable, but I was hoping more (again my bad explaining), to come back with the longest miles on each bike, and then I could sort that data out easier.  I think with this the data is all there, but it's a full table scan.

Comment: Your question didn't make it clear that there are multiple rows and you need to find the one with the max. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Comment: You should post your schema, sample data, and the result you're trying to achieve, that will make things clearer. A sqlfiddle is also helpful.